# Can the equivalence of electric and magnetic fields be demonstrated using just two charged particles rather than a particle and wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

The equivalence of the electric and magnetic fields can be demonstrated by considering a current flowing in a wire and a test charge moving relative to the wire. In the frame of reference where the wire is stationary and the charge is moving there is a magnetic force applied to the test charge due to the magnetic field created by the wire. If you then consider a reference frame in which the test charge is not moving then there is no magnetic force, however the length contraction of the charges in the wire produces a net electric field that creates an equivalent electric force on the charged particle in this reference frame.

I can understand this mathematical derivation, but in another scenario where the current carrying wire is replaced by a single moving charge, this equivalence appears to breakdown. If you start with a frame of reference where one of the charges is moving to the left and the other charge is moving to the right, at the point where they pass each other they will be attracted by a magnetic field in addition to the electric field. Now if you take another reference where one of the charges is stationary and the other is moving left at twice the speed, there is no longer a magnetic force of attraction by either particle. But in this case the length contraction of the single charge does not increase the electric field to compensate, as it does with the concentration of charges in the wire.

So in this scenario how can you derive the same equivalence?

Comment: The electric field does change in the second frame, in fact the electric field changes by a factor of $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

Comment: Thank you for this insight, on further reading I can see that by applying the Lorentz transformation the electric field lines are distorted by the length contraction as you indicate. So the contraction of charges in the wire in my original example is really just a layman’s thought experiment, really you need to apply the 4-vector transformation to see the complete picture

Comment: I believe the current in the wire just makes it more clear in terms of length contraction. To get the full description one needs to use the Leonard-Wiechert potentials/fields.